# Inserting dynamic multiple values in a single column in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i wish to insert multiple entries in a single column..
inserting requires taking the values from the form in text field..
help me with retrieval..

here is my code for page1..

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cse");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["bupin"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='1quiz1[".$row["bupin"]."]'>". "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

here is the code for final11.php

```
if (isset($_POST["1quiz1"])) 
{
    foreach ($presence as $key => $val) 
    {
        mysqli_query($con,"Insert into cse ");
    }
}
echo "Entered successfully..";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["1quiz1"])) {

    $keys = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach ($presence as $key => $val) {
        $keys .= $key+",";
        $values .= $val+",";
    }

    // remove last commas
    $keys = substr($keys, 0,-1);
    $values = substr($values, 0,-1);

    //insert
    mysqli_query($con,"Insert into cse (".$keys.") values (".$values.")");

    // you can here check the errors then if you need
}
echo "Entered successfully..";
```

Comment: i've made a column named 1quiz1 where i would like to update the values as entered by the user.. plz check

//update

` mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE cse SET 1quiz1(".$keys.") values (".$values.")");`

also, bupin is my primary key

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert anything inside your input name attribute brackets. in other words, you have to make it something like the following:

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='1quiz1[]'>". "</td></tr>";
```